# cannot find code for hover effect on fa icon

Tags: html, css

The question is regarding my portfolio here:

[My Portfolio](https://vouzalis.com/kompetencer.php)

If you hover over the "Marketing Automation" there is a small fa fa-tablet icon to the left. That tablet is getting blue when you hover over. I do not want that one to get blue, but it should stay white. All the fa icons are getting blue when you hover over them. In my frustrations I tried to delete all the CSS, to see if that help. But the hover blue is still coming.

I cannot figure out where that is comming from. I have been looking everywhere I think. Does anybody have an idea where the hover effect is from out from the inspector window?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="service small">
                <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>
                <a href="artikler/marketing-automation.php"><h3 class="kompetenceLinks">Marketing Automation</h3></a>
                <p>
                     Et meget stærkt og endnu overset værktøj der <i>vil </i>skabe en automatiseret og personaliseret 
                     kunderelation, og dermed være en faktor til øget salgspotentialer.

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Default browser styles for links on hover are blue. If you don't want this behavior, override it with your own CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in theme_color.css in line 40 you have to change

```
.services .service:hover .fa, 
.popular-posts li a:hover .fa, 
.sidebar .social li a:hover, 
.block-thumbnail .block-data h3 a:hover {
    color: #09F;
}
```

to

```
.services .service:hover .fa, 
.popular-posts li a:hover .fa, 
.sidebar .social li a:hover, 
.block-thumbnail .block-data h3 a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

or you override it in another file...

that should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you a lot for that. That did the trick. I can first accept your answer in 9 minutes. But how did you find out that it was in the theme.color?

Answer (score 0):

The problem must come from your custom CSS, i added this code to mine, and i don't get the issue, only the link is getting underlined, and not the icon. Try to have a look to your "a" style